# onclick button changes default text in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

Given a textarea and two buttons as follows :

**HTML**

```
<ul style="text-align:center;">
 <li class="button btn btn-outline button-exclusive" id="button1">
        <div style="font-size:16px;text-align:text-align:center;">
           <span class="buttonIconSupport">Contact 1</span>
        </div>
    </li>
<li class="button btn btn-outline button-exclusive"  id="button2">
           <span class="buttonIconTeam">contact2</span>
</li>
</ul>

<textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" style="height:200px;width:765px">text1_contact1</textarea>
```

i want to  click on the first button => a default text appears in the textarea "text1_contact1"
and if i click on the other button => the default text changes in the textarea "text2_contact2"

for now i have a text when i click on the textarea it disappears ( as a first step ) but i want a different default text for each button click.

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(){
$("#message").focus(function() {
    if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
        this.value = '';
    }
  })
  .blur(function() {
    if (this.value === '') {
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: You just need a click handler to set the text of the textarea? Or is there more?

Comment: yes just  the click on the button sets which default text

Comment: and then the user clicks on the textarea the text disappears ( i've already done that )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4gpoxajv/)**

```
<ul style="text-align:center;">
 <li class="button btn btn-outline button-exclusive" data-default="text1_contact1" id="button1">
        <div style="font-size:16px;text-align:text-align:center;">
           <span class="buttonIconSupport">Contact 1</span>
        </div>
    </li>
<li class="button btn btn-outline button-exclusive" data-default="text2_contact2"  id="button2">
           <span class="buttonIconTeam">contact2</span>
</li>
</ul>
<textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" style="height:200px;width:765px">text1_contact1</textarea>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(){
    $("#message").val($(this).data('default'));
    setFunctionality();

});


$(document).on('click', '#button2', function(){
    $("#message").val($(this).data('default'));
    setFunctionality();
    });

function setFunctionality()
{
    $("#message").focus(function() {
    if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
        this.value = '';
    }
  })
  .blur(function() {
    if (this.value === '') {
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
});
}
```

**UPDATE**

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4gpoxajv/1/)**

Add a `data-default` attribute to your `textarea`

Then make below changes to your JS

```
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(){
    $("#message").val($(this).data('default'));
    $("#message").data('default',$(this).data('default'));
});

$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#message").val('text1_contact1');
    $("#message").data('default','text1_contact1');
});

$(document).on('click', '#button2', function(){
    $("#message").val($(this).data('default'));
   $("#message").data('default',$(this).data('default'));
    });

    $(document).on('focus','#message',function() {
        console.log(this.value + ' ' + this.defaultValue);
    if (this.value === $(this).data('default')) {
        this.value = '';
    }
  }).on('blur','#message',function() {
    if (this.value === '') {
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    }
});
```

Comment: in the button 2 even if i put the function setFunctionality() the text doesn't disappear onclick

Comment: the first one desappears "text1_contact1" because it's the one set in the textarea and the second one is in the attribute data-default it doesn't disappear

Comment: hi thank you for your answer it helps a lot, but i have other inputs than the textarea and if i select something else the default text in the attribute data-default appears

Comment: What are those other inputs?

Answer (score 1):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2k22h3hy/2/

Instead of creating global variables, you can use custom attribute in tags itself. Assign a `defaultValue` custom attribute and manipulate it on button click. This way you need to bind the blur and focus event only once and just change the `textarea` value by its `defaultValue` attribute.

JS:

```
$("#message").focus(function() {
        //empty the textarea
        this.value = '';
  })
  .blur(function() {
        //change textarea text to default text
        this.value = $(this).attr('data-defaultValue');
});
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(){
    //change textarea's defaultText attribute value
    $("#message").data('defaultValue',"text1_contact1");
});
$(document).on('click', '#button2', function(){
    //change textarea's defaultText attribute value
    $("#message").data('defaultValue',"text1_contact2");
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul style="text-align:center;">
 <li class="button btn btn-outline button-exclusive" id="button1">
        <div style="font-size:16px;text-align:text-align:center;">
           <span class="buttonIconSupport">Contact 1</span>
        </div>
    </li>
<li class="button btn btn-outline button-exclusive"  id="button2">
           <span class="buttonIconTeam">contact2</span>
</li>
</ul>

<textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" style="height:200px;width:765px" data-defaultValue="text1_contact1">text1_contact1</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change a textarea value using the jQuery function (as it seems you use it) $.val("what you want here").
So you would have:

```
//On button click, define a default value for the textarea
$("#button1").on('click', function(){
    $("#message").val("text1_contact1");
});

//On textarea focus clear the content
$("#message").focus(function(){
    $("#message").val("");
});
```

You can also use the placeholder attribute if you don't need the default value to be retrieved.